# Can I masturbate after marriage if I'm not satisfied with my wife?

Tags: nikah, husband-wife, masturbation

As-Salam-Wa-Laikum.

I've a question related to masturbation. I know, Masturbation is Haram. But, here's my situation.

I'm married for 23 years but for many years, I don't get excited for my wife and she also can't make me excited.

She thinks, it's my part to make her ready and myself too. However, for many years, I forcefully make myself available to make her satisfy - **which is my duty**.

But, I don't get satisfied and I don't get it done. I make myself cold forcefully without completing my satisfaction.

My question is, ***is it permissible to do masturbation in such a situation*** (after making my wife satisfied, which make her tired and she can't take it anymore)?

I need to do something to make my brain cold but I don't know what to do? I live in U.S. and I can't take a second wife nor do I want to divorce her.

Answer (score 1):

You can not masturbate yourself but you can masturbate using your wife. You are not limited to sex in her vagina she can also stimulate you with her hands, thighs, breasts, lips (but not anus) it is perfectly allowed to do this. In addition to that, I would advise you to go see a sex therapist as they can provide counseling which will help you solve this problem.